# There is two file import in flutter with same file name but different case

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

[image: Duplicate file import]
Picture shown that two imports exists.`../SignUp_repo.dart` and `../signup_repo.dart`.

I have tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` but still got the same issue. If I import between both, only one import will work **(The one with uppercase file name import)**.

Hope anyone can help me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `as` prefix while importing.

```dart
import '../SignUp/domain/repositories/SignUp_repo.dart' as signUp
```

And use it like  `signUp.SignUpRepo`. You can do the same for another.